# Python: Iterating through excel column and getting values with win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm using Python 3.5 and win32com to iterate through an excel document rows (only from the first column) and get all the values from it, the best would be in a simple list. I tried the following implementation but there are a few problems with it:

```
excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(myfile2)
worksheet = workbook.Sheets('Sheet1')
data = excel_app.Range("A1:A60")
print(data)

for i in data:
    if i is not None:
        print(i)
```

The problems are mainly with: "data = excel_app.Range("A1:A60")"

1. This takes the first 60 rows, I would like to get only as many rows as there is data in the excel file, otherwise either i don't get enough data, or i get too much and i end up with a bunch of 'None'
2. It returns a Tuple, so i can't modify it in order to remove the 'None' values if i get more data than the spreadsheet has.

Comment: Any specific reason you're using win32com? It's one of the harder ways to do it.

Comment: yes, I need win32com because it's the only library i know that lets me embed objects into excel if my condition is true (if i is not None), with the following code:
Embedded_object.Add(ClassType=None, Filename=file_loction, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=True, Left=3, Top=0, Width=50, Height=50)

Comment: Ok, understood... but if reading is so unconvenient and embedding is only possible with win32com - why not mix it? use win32com for everything which works and has no alternative and the simple reading issues can be solved with xlrd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the row count by using:

```
worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

where [UsedRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) represents all the cells that have contained a value at any time.

Once you have the data in your tuple, you can copy it into a list for processing - e.g. new_list = data[:].

If you want to copy into a new list and remove None values at the same time:

```
new_list = [ item for item in data if item is not None]
```

Comment: For some reason, this gives unexpected high counts at more complicated sheets, possibly because later rows used to contain data. Would it be possible to determine the `UsedRange` on current data presence in a certain column, say, `A`?

Comment: @Mast This is a well-known phenomena - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for a fairly comprehensive discussion. While it's VBA, the same principles apply. I would suggest that you post your specific requirements as a question - for example whether you have to use win32com like this original poster - and then you should get an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you wouldn't mind using xlrd it would be much easier I think.
This would be sth like

```
import xlrd

xlf = xlrd.open_workbook('/wherever/file/may/roam/asdf.xlsx')
xls = xlf.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
data = xls.col_values(0)
```